# functions as a parameter vs in a loop Time Complicity

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity, big-o

I am assuming that when passing a function(let's call it function B) as a parameter to function A ,its not necessarily adding to big-O of function A.
`functionA(functionB)`
or
`len(range(n))`

but if a function is being called while iterating over it, then it does change the big-o time complicity.

then wouldn't looping over a built-in function do the same?

here is an example in python:

```py
a=list() # of some array 
for _ in range(a):
     a.count(1)
```

I have no CS background, can someone clarify this.

Comment: Your first assumption is wrong. Also, we don't pass a function as another functions' parameter usually. Maybe you can read some basic complexity analysis to get an idea.

Comment: " Also, we don't pass a function as another functions' parameter usually." People do that all the time.

Comment: "but if a function is being called while iterating over it, then it does change the big-o time complicity." It depends on the function being called. "then wouldn't looping over a built-in function do the same?" You don't loop over the *function*, you loop over the result of calling that function. Again, it all depends *on what the function does*. Also, I'm not sure what being a built-in function has to do with any of this, that sort of distinction is not really relevant when it comes to algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "passing a function" into function B, unless you mean with a decorator... anyhow, if you call a function within another function it's safe to assume that you will have to consider the nested function's time complexity. For example, if I make a function:

```py
def funcA(i_max, j_max):
    for i in range(i_max):
        for j in range(j_max):
            print("aaaaaaaah")
```

which has complexity `O(i_max * j_max)`, and then I make another function:

```py
def funcB(k_max):
    for k in range(k_max):
        funcA(some_i, some_j)
```

then naturally funcB will have complexity `O(k_max * some_i * some_j)` – so you do have to consider the big-O of the other function.